# app crashes when i try to scroll the tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

when i try to scroll my tableview it crashes the app,below shown is my code please help me to fix this issue

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row---%d",indexPath.row);
    UILabel *skuLbl;
//   *cellImgView;
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        NSLog(@"indexPath cell");
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autorelease];
        UIImageView *cellImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,20,717,125)];
        cellImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImgView];
        skuLbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(62,20,680,125)];
        skuLbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        skuLbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"helvetica" size:40];
        skuLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:skuLbl];
        cell.selectionStyle=NO;    
        tableView.separatorColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    }



//  NSLog(@"inside cell--%@",[[appDelegateObj.parsedRowsSku objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"SKU"]);
//  skuLbl.text=[[appDelegateObj.parsedRowsSku objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"SKU"];
    skuLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very readable code.

Comment: Have you attached the debugger? If so, at which line does the code break?

Comment: -1: Your original question was absolutely unformatted. After having asked more than 20 questions already you should know how to format. And you should know that posting the information about the crash (exceptions, messages in the debugger, etc.) is almost a must. Should we guess what kind of crash happened? You want us to help you, so please help us by putting more effort in your question.

Comment: I cannot see any source of a crash.
BUT: you never release cellImgView and skuLbl.
Why not placing a [skuLbl release] and [cellImgView release] after adding them to the subview?

Answer (score 4):

When you scroll your table view it tries to reuse its cells so

```
 if(cell==nil){        
    ...
 }
```

may not get called and your skuLbl pointer remains not initialized. So later you're trying to access that invalid pointer and that results in crash.

You need to get reference to label outside of initialization block to make sure it is always valid:

```
UILabel *skuLbl = nil;
static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil){
    ...
    skuLbl.tag = 100;
    ...
}
skuLbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your number of rows are equals to the size of your array or whatever you're using with this method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  return [self.myArray count]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code as below::

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    UILabel *skuLbl = nil;
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil) {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autorelease];

        UIImageView *cellImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,20,717,125)];
        cellImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImgView];

        skuLbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(62,20,680,125)];
        skuLbl.tag = 100;
        skuLbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        skuLbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"helvetica" size:40];
        skuLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:skuLbl];

        cell.selectionStyle=NO;    
        tableView.separatorColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
       // This method called at creation and scrolling of tableview for every individual cell. 
       // Due to creation and scrolling of tableview skuLbl refrence get nil
       // So get new refrence of skuLbl from cell's contentView as below
       skuLbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    }

    skuLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```